# How to disable client-side form field validation in Django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

How do you disable client-side JS form field validation in Django's admin, specifically for URLFields?

I have a client that doesn't want to enter "http://" for all URL fields, which seems reasonable. This is easy to do with the server-side form validation, but the client-side still prevents the form from being submitted unless the user enters "http://". How do I turn that off, just for that field? I'm looking through the code for models.URLField/forms.URLField/URLValidator, but I don't see an easy way to turn it off without reimplementing the widget.

Edit: Example of the JS validation I want to disable.
[image]

Comment: What? Django doesn't do any client-side validation. By definition, that's the job of client-side code, ie Javascript.

Comment: all statics (v. 1.6) located in `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js` you can inspect in your browser which of them are loading on that page, also you can inspect event listeners of that DOM node and simply override function (using same name) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I believe you're incorrect. See madzohan's comment for the location of Django's Javascript files, and my screenshot of the JS behavior that Django generates by default for URLField client-side validation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I said in the comment, Django doesn't do any client-side validation. The error you're seeing is coming from the browser's own HTML5 validation: see [this website](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/3-url.html) for an example and explanation.

You can disable HTML5 validation by adding `novalidate` to the surrounding `form` element.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that was built-in to the browser. Thanks for the insight.